# How to print the date from milliseconds based on Macintosh time

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a integer representing the milliseconds that have passed since 12:00 A.M. on January 1, 1904. I believe this is also known as Macintosh time. It is the base time used by the original Mac OS.

Normally I would do:

```
int millis = 1284543608;
Date date = new Date(millis);
System.out.println(date);
```

However, this uses the Unix epoch and will thus not return an accurate date.

How would you print the date using milliseconds obtained from Macintosh time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Calendar macEpoch = Calendar.getInstance();
    macEpoch.setTimeInMillis(0);
    macEpoch.set(1904,0, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    //On a mac
    Calendar macTimeForToday = Calendar.getInstance();

    System.out.println("ms since mac epoch: " + macTimeForToday.getTimeInMillis());
    System.out.println("ms since epoch: " + (macTimeForToday.getTimeInMillis() + macEpoch.getTimeInMillis()));
```

Notice that the whole translation occurs when you add `-2082880800000L` to `macTime.getTimeInMillis()`

Comment: Just as a hint, I understand that there is a bug with this method which doesn't zero out the milli seconds, so your calculation is going to be "slightly" off...

Comment: Interesting of you to bring up, I think I've fixed it by first setting the time to the Unix epoch (although any multiple of 1000 should do)

Comment: I'd give that a +1...you might want to correct you difference value though, your method now gives `-2082880800000L` ;)

Comment: Silly me I should have noticed since it wasn't a multiple of 1000. There's that error you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

So we know the epoch for both, we need to calculate the difference between the two...

We can start with a standard `Calendar` out get the time in milliseconds

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1904);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

Which returns `-2082880800000`.  So between the Mac time and the Java time, there is a difference of `2082880800000` milliseconds....I'd probably store this somewhere.

Any time you need to convert from Mac time to Java time, you will need subtract this value from the Mac time to bring it line with the Java Time...

```
long javaTime = macTime - 2082880800000L;
```

For example...

Comment: setting the HOUR_OF_DAY field to 12 is 12PM, not 12AM

Comment: @RonE Yeah, was just checking that :P